# Split a json file based on number of records in ADF

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Copy data activity in azure data factory to read restapi json and save in blob as json file.
I want to split the file as multiple files if the number of records in file exceeds 200k records. (example: maximum number of records in one file is 200k )How can I achieve this azure data factory copy data activity.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to use dataflow for that partition.

Comment: If you want to split the larger json file into smaller csv files, you can use copy activity itself. In sink settings, you can give the value for `Max rows per file`. Refer the [img](https://i.imgur.com/DTaR5Qo.png). This will split the files and each file will have the rows as specified. If your sink is to be Json file only, then as @Pratik Lad suggested, use dataflow transformation

Comment: @PratikLad, can you please help with how to use dataflow to do the same?

Comment: Check the below answer

Answer (score 0):

If the sink is of delimited text, you can use copy activity itself to split the larger files into smaller file. In order to do that, in sink settings of copy activity, you can mention the required value for `Max rows per file`.

[image]

Sink file  will be created in the format `<sourcefilename>_<000xx>.txt`.

- To split the file using dataflow, follow the below steps.

1. Take the source transformation with the source json dataset.
2. Then take the surrogate key transformation and row_number to each row. Set start value and step value as 1. In this demo, I have created a column called `row_num` as a surrogate key.

[image]

3. Then add derived column transformation and add a new column. Value for that column is given as `toInteger((row_num-1)/10)`. Here row_num is the surrogate key column which is created in second step. `10` denotes that the maximum rows in each file should be of 10. you can replace the value with the required number.

[image]

4. Then again add derived column transformation to add the filename as a column. Here file_name is set as `concat("sink_",toString(file_part))`

[image]

5. Then add a sink transformation with json dataset. In the sink settings, give `Name file as column data` as file name option value. Give the `file_name` as  value for the column name .

[image]

If the pipeline containing this dataflow is run, large Json file is split into smaller files containing maximum 10 rows.

Comment: If the solution is helpful, you can mark this as answer